# vue.js prevent one data element from trigger update

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi is there a way to stop triggering updated method in vue instance only for one element?. Here is my code,

vue instance..

```
           var vm = new Vue({
                el: '#el',
                data: {
                    cap: "",
                    radius: "",
                    var1: "",
                    var2: "",
                    var3: "",
                    items: null,
                }
                updated: function () {
                    axios.post('{{ url('car_result') }}', {data: this.$data})
                           .then(response => {
                            this.items = response.data;
                        });
                }
            });
```

This is my dom.

```
              <div id="el">
                    <input v-model="cap" type="text">
                    <input v-model="radius" type="text">
                    <input v-model="var1" type="text">
                    <input v-model="var2" type="text">
                    <input v-model="vat3" type="text">

                    <div class="item" v-for="item in items">
                        {{ item.id }}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here I need to **stop triggering updated method when items changed**

Comment: why do you want to stop triggering? on first look I think you may be looking for a different hook, like `mounted`.

Comment: to be honest I need to trigger update for all data elements other than items since this does number of unwanted axios back-end requests. Mounted will not do the trick sadly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about grouping your input variables into a single `input` and then set up a watcher and update `items` only when the `input` changes ?

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  data: {
    input: {
      cap: "",
      radius: "",
      var1: "",
      var2: "",
      var3: ""
    },
    items: null,
  },
  watch: {
    input: {
      handler (newInput) {
        axios.post('{{ url('car_result') }}', { data: newInput })
          .then(response => {
            this.items = response.data;
          });
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
});
```

In your template:

```
<div id="el">
  <input v-model="input.cap" type="text">
  <input v-model="input.radius" type="text">
  <input v-model="input.var1" type="text">
  <input v-model="input.var2" type="text">
  <input v-model="input.vat3" type="text">

  <div class="item" v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.id }}
  </div>
</div>
```